# <HOME> key is unwanted set to "toggle upercase"

Tags: key-bindings, color, tmux

During insert mode my <kbd>Home</kbd> key is set to toggle case of character which is very annoying. I tried this command to search for any settings, but failed to solve the problem. I would like to set it to go at the beginning of a line ("0").

```
:redir! > vim_key_setting.txt
silent verbose imap
redir END
```

I pasted this file on pastebin.com: [vim_keys_map.txt](https://pastebin.com/cXbn4Euw)

Pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> key while in **insert mode** shows following message in the status line:

```
^[[1~
```

Update: It seems to be a tmux problem with the escape characters, since the bug doesn't occur in  tilix,konsole or alacritty(w/o tmux).

Weird enough the <kbd>END</kbd> key works and `vim -g` (vim gui) runs as expected.

Comment: In Insert mode what is inserted if you type <Ctrl-v><Home>?

Comment: `^[[1~` as posted above.

Comment: Looks like Vim doesn't detect `^[[1~` as the "home key" and treats it as literal text (`~` toggles case). What is the value of your `TERM` environment variable? Usually setting that to the correct value fixes things (e.g. `tmux-256color` for tmux).

Comment: Yesterday I played quite a lot and I saw that tmux was upgraded to 3.3a. They did something with the $TERM setting. Before the update I had to set it to `TERM=xterm-256color`. In the tmux's instruction it is said that there is no need to set this variable. So I unset it in my `.zshrc` . However the `HOME` key works in that case. The only problem is that I can't get vim in color now :(. Without setting `echo $TERM` shows me `tmux-256color`. I also played within the `.tmux.conf` setting `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color` ... but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise it wasn't a tmux problem, even the bug occurred only when a terminal (tilix, konsole, alacritty, kitty) used tmux.

First of all tmux (>3.3a) doesn't need an environment variable any more like `TERM=xterm-256color` nor is it necessary to set the `default-terminal` variable in the `tmux.conf` file.

The reason for the bug  was an installed theme. Following the instructions I set

```
    set termguicolors
```

Uncommenting it saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following setting in your `.vimrc`

```
set <Home>=^[[1~
```

Where `^[` is inserted using the following key sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: It doesn't help. It seems to be an issue with the terminal; I'm using tmux - alacrity .With another konsole (tilix) there is no problem. So I assume the fault behaviour has to do with the escape characters of alacritty/tmux. It has chaned this week so I will look at the package upgrades of my debian/sid.